# skip verify authenticity token vs protect from forgery with null session?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm building a Rails app that needs to receive POST'd emails from Mailgun. All OK, I have a controller and routes for that.

All requests receives `HTTP 422` because Rails says `Invalid Authenticity Token`, which is really expected in this case.

I won't use `rack-cors` because I only allow Mailgun proceeding requests authenticating with its own signature mechanism.

Here my question: Should I use `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` or should I use `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `protect_from_forgery with: :null_session` as it won't contaminate any existing session.